# Merge similar hours from Date Column into one

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

```
   Date                   MW
0 2017-01-01 09:00:00      1
1 2017-01-01 09:00:00      1
2 2017-01-01 09:00:00      1
3 2017-01-01 10:00:00      1
4 2017-01-01 10:00:00      1
```

I want to add up values for all the repeated hours and convert it into a single row. For example, for 09:00:00, the final value should be 3 MW.

I tried groupby but it says missing values for hours that are not in the dataset. Also, df.resample('H').sum() gives weird results.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't reproduce, because when I do `df.groupby('Date').sum()` it works fine for me

Comment: [Can you show us what the weird results look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]). Also post the exact error message you are receiving

Comment: That's what it gives.
         Date                                MW
0 2017-01-01 09:00:00               111
1 2017-01-01 10:00:00          11222237
2 2017-01-01 11:00:00      111314161119
3 2017-01-01 12:00:00  1316201318152322
4 2017-01-01 13:00:00        1923242120

Answer (score 1):

Why not considering datetime as string while doing group by?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2017-01-01 09:00:00','2017-01-01 09:00:00','2017-01-01 10:00:00','2017-01-01 10:00:00'],
              'MW':[1,2,1,1]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).sum()
```

output:

```
                  Date  MW
0  2017-01-01 09:00:00   3
1  2017-01-01 10:00:00   2
```

Comment: When I try to do this, it gives me

0 2017-01-01 09:00:00               111
1 2017-01-01 10:00:00          11222237
2 2017-01-01 11:00:00      111314161119
3 2017-01-01 12:00:00  1316201318152322
4 2017-01-01 13:00:00        1923242120

Comment: Corrected the error. My MW column had dtype as object. Converted it to int and applied groupby

Comment: df.dtypes and you should see Date column as Object, MW as int

Comment: Is there a way I could add missing hours with zeros in MW column to this data? @CSMaverick

Comment: like you want to add 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11,00 for this particular case??

Comment: Yes, and add zeros in MW column alongside

Comment: date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='1/2/2017', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['MW'] = 0
try this

Comment: Still working on merging the two dataframes on index

Comment: did u get the anwer? if not try this

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2017', end='1/2/2017', freq='H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df2.Date.astype(str)
df2["MW"] = 0
new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['Date','MW'],keep='last')

Comment: Getting the size of new_df as 13550 when I try it for the entire year instead of 8760.

Comment: date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/1/2019', freq='H')[:-1]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df2.Date.astype(str)
df2["MW"] = 0
new_df = pd.concat([df2,df]).drop_duplicates(['Date','MW'],keep='last')

Comment: You should get the right output.. I don't know how you're doing but try above comment. You should maintain data type across the dataframes

Comment: Used merge to get the output. Thanks for the help